# Hide and show button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a task in school and I think Javascript is really hard. Now in the beginning I need to google everything and I only find solutions in different libraries.

In this case I need to use Vanilla JS. When I click on logout button it need to toggle and show the login button.

In the task I cant change the HTML only add JS.

// student

```html
   <button class="signin-btn is-hidden">Log in </button>
    <button class="signout-btn">Log out </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add click event listeners to both of the buttons to change its own `display` to `none` and display the other button.

```js
var login = document.querySelector('.signin-btn'),
logout = document.querySelector('.signout-btn');
login.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  this.classList.add('is-hidden');//adds is-hidden class
  logout.classList.remove('is-hidden');//removes is-hidden class
});
logout.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  this.classList.add('is-hidden');
  login.classList.remove('is-hidden');
});
```

```css
.is-hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="signin-btn is-hidden">Log in </button>
<button class="signout-btn">Log out </button>
```

Comment: This works great but the function is never running when I put in in my document.

Comment: @E_BE Put it in a `script` tag at the bottom of the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

here's a extremely basic way to do it, I would recommend using more advanced techniques later

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('but').style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('butother').style.display = "block"
}

function changeother() {
  document.getElementById('butother').style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('but').style.display = "block"
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="but" onclick='change()'>log in </button>
  <button id="butother" onclick='changeother()'>log out </button>
</body>

</html>
```